# Let $f(x)=e^{x}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ then which of the following statements are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $f(x)=e^{x}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. Which of the following statements are correct?

1. There is a real $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-1-x|\leq Cx^{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
2. There is a real $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}|\leq C|x|^{3}$ for al $x\in[-1,1]$.
3. There is a real $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}|\leq Cx^{4}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
4. There is a real $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}|\leq Cx^{4}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

I was solving questions of real analysis for a competitive exam. I got stuck at this one. The answers given are $(2)$ and $(4)$ but I could not see how. For $(1)$, whatever $x$ I take, I can always find a real number $C$ such that $(1)$ is true but I could not see how this is incorrect (same for the option $(3)$). I understand how $(2)$ and $(4)$ can be correct but I am really confused about options $(1)$ and $(3)$. Please help. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: *“whatever $x$ I take, I can always find a real number $C$ such that $(1)$ is true”* – But $(1)$ means that there is a *single* number $C$ such that the inequality holds for *all* numbers $x$. I.e. $C$ must be *independent* of $x$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, $(1)$ and $(3)$ are wrong because the exponential functions grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, I completely get it now. To your first comment, do I have to fix $C$? I mean if C is independent of $x$ then I will have to fix $C$ and choose $x$, right?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @MartinR, now I have doubts about (2) and (4) as to why they are incorrect. It would be really helpful if you could spare some time.. thanks in advance.